# How to deal with a variable string in django queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-queryset

I am  trying to write a django queryset.

```
    Review.objects.filter(user__exact=user).count()
```

The problem is that the "user__exact" has to match with the current value of the "cuser" variable (the user who is currently logged in), and then return the count of the reviews submitted by that user. But if I do that I am getting this error.

```
    TemplateSyntaxError at /dashboard/
    Could not parse the remainder: '(user__exact=cuser).count()' from 'Review.objects.filter(user__exact=user).count()'
```

Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: Why are you using a string? `cuser` is already a variable.

Comment: Yes, It is a variable. Where I went wrong was that, I tried to get the value of the queryset in the template by including it in the "{{ }}". Now I changed it to the corresponding view function, and replaced "user=cuser" with "user=request.user" and returned the value in a JSON list along with other values for the template. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `cuser` variabe is instance of User class you dont need `exact` in this case, just use: `Review.objects.filter(user=cuser).count()`. 
Use `exact` if `cuser` is string (e.g. username) like this: `Review.objects.filter(user__username__exact=cuser).count()` or obtain user instance first with `get` method: `user = User.objects.get(username=cuser)`. And use this instance with filter: `Review.objects.filter(user=user).count()`

Comment: Thanks! It is a variable. Where I went wrong was that, I tried to get the value of the queryset in the template by including it in the "{{ }}". Now I changed it to the corresponding view function, and replaced "user=cuser" with "user=request.user" and returned the value in a JSON list along with other values for the template. It worked.